# Unable to view first JPanel added at the center of frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Have a look at my code when I try to add a stage at the center of installer screen I get nothing on opening `JFrame`. I achieved same code by placing `add()` method in overriden `setVisible()` method, I intentionally not placed working code because i want to know whats wrong with this piece of code.

```
public class InstallerFrameDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private JPanel masterPanel;
    private JPanel titlePanel;
    private JLabel title;
    private JPanel centerView;
    private JPanel currentProgress;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    private JButton next;
    private JButton back;
    private JButton exit;
    private JButton finished;
    private InstallerModel model;   
    private NavigationButtonsListener navButtonsListener;

    public InstallerFrameDemo(InstallerModel model) {
        if (model == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        this.model = model;

        masterPanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel = new JPanel();
        title = new JLabel("Welcome to application installer");
        centerView = new JPanel();
        currentProgress = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        next = new JButton("Next");
        back = new JButton("Back");
        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        finished = new JButton("Finished");

        navButtonsListener = new NavigationButtonsListener();

        add(model.getCurrentStage());

        back.setEnabled(false);
        finished.setEnabled(false);

        if (model.getStageCount() <= 1) {
            next.setEnabled(false);
            exit.setEnabled(false);
            finished.setEnabled(true);
        }

        exit.addActionListener(navButtonsListener);
        next.addActionListener(navButtonsListener);
        back.addActionListener(navButtonsListener);
        finished.addActionListener(navButtonsListener);

        masterPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        titlePanel.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
        centerView.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        currentProgress.setBackground(Color.decode("#26b8ee"));

        title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));

        title.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 18));
        currentProgress.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(4, 4));

        masterPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        centerView.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        titlePanel.add(title);

        centerView.add(currentProgress, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        buttonPanel.add(exit);
        buttonPanel.add(back);
        buttonPanel.add(next);
        buttonPanel.add(finished);

        masterPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        masterPanel.add(centerView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        masterPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setContentPane(masterPanel);

        setTitle("Welcome to application installer");
        setSize(800, 600);
    }

    protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
        if (comp == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (centerView != null) {
            centerView.removeAll();

            // able to see
            centerView.add(currentProgress, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); // successfully added

            if (comp instanceof InstallerStage) {
                InstallerStage stage = (InstallerStage) comp;
                title.setText(stage.getTitle());
                this.centerView.add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER, index);
                System.out.println(comp); // For first stage toString return - in first stage
                // Got the output - in first stage but no change in view

                repaint(); // Test 1
                revalidate(); // Test 2
            }
        } else {
            super.addImpl(comp, constraints, index);
        }
    }


    public InstallerModel getInstallerModel() {
        return model;
    }

    private class NavigationButtonsListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getSource() == exit) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (ae.getSource() == back) {
                finished.setEnabled(false);
                exit.setEnabled(true);
                InstallerStage prevStage = model.getPreviousStage();
                if (prevStage != null) {
                    add(prevStage);
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    if (model.getCurrentStageIndex() == 0) {
                        back.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ae.getSource() == next) {
                InstallerStage currentStage = model.getCurrentStage();
                if (currentStage.process()) {
                    InstallerStage nextStage = model.getNextStage();
                    if (nextStage != null) {
                        add(nextStage);
                        back.setEnabled(true);
                        if (model.getCurrentStageIndex() == model
                                .getStageCount() - 1) {
                            next.setEnabled(false);
                            finished.setEnabled(true);
                            exit.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ae.getSource() == finished) {
                InstallerStage currentStage = model.getCurrentStage();
                if (currentStage.process()) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless the code is runnable, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the overriden method `protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index)` that is giving you a problem. If you want to add something to the JFrame centerView, just add to it, like you add JButtons exit, back next and finished to buttonPanel; don't override addImpl() method. As you can see in the JavaDocs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29), overriding that method, children are added to the contentPane instead of the frame.
Try removing the overrided method and you'll see than it's all visible, except the center panel that you have to implement somewhere else.